# How do I remove the download button from WP mediaelement.js

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement.js

[Need Help Removing Download Button_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yft5q.png)

I have attached an image of the media player on my WP page.  It just appeared on my player and it wasn't there before (last month).  I haven't done any plugin upgrades for mediaelement.js so I don't know where this is coming from. I would like to remove the download button, but I am not sure where in WordPress nor how to hide it.

```
<td class="files">  <audio id="wp_mep_2" controls="controls" preload="none">

        <source src="http://xxxxxxx.org/?page_id=1743&amp;show&amp;file_name=JesusistheDifferenceMaker.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        <object width="250" height="30" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://xxxxxxx.org/wp-content/plugins/media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player/mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf">
            <param name="movie" value="http://xxxxxxx.org/wp-content/plugins/media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player/mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf">
            <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&amp;file=http://xxxxxxx.org/?page_id=1743&amp;show&amp;file_name=JesusistheDifferenceMaker.mp3">           
        </object>       
    </audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#wp_mep_2').mediaelementplayer({
        m:1

        ,features: ['playpause','current','progress','duration','volume','tracks','fullscreen']
        ,audioWidth:250,audioHeight:30
    });
});
</script>
</td>
```

Comment: does anyone know how to remove the download button?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like mediaelement.js was not initialized and browser use default html5 player. (In chrome) You can recognize from default mediaelement.js skin `http://www.mediaelementjs.com/`

See [w3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all) where is used default player

or

See on video example:

[Without mediaelement.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyLSH.png)

[With mediaelement.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFW2b.png)

I recomend you to check or log init funcion or run some debug enablePluginDebug:true like mediaelement option.

Comment: The answer provided helps, but still doesn't block/prevent user from Right Clicking on Mouse and downloading the audio/video.  I don't want people to be able to download at all.  In your W3School example I could still download the video/audio